# custom UITableViewCell with different size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a class which subclasses the UITableViewCell. This cell will be used in two different 
UITableViewController class, one with a size of 200x400 and one with a size of 200x600. The question is what do I need to change in my implementation? Can I override the constructor of the cell so that I can pass in the width and height of the cell that I want? If yes then how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your UITableViewCell-subclass:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRrect)newFrame {
    [super setFrame:newFrame];

    // perform operations using the new frame.
    // ex.: 
    // CGRect rect = self.label.frame;
    // rect.size.width = newFrame.size.width - 20.f;
    // self.label.frame = rect;
}
```

Comment: I would also like to set up the font for the larger size cell, is that another method?

Comment: If you know both heights and font-sizes, you can add this to the method `self.label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:(newFrame.size.width == __firstHeight__)?__firstFontSize__:__secondFontSize__)];`

Comment: Replace the `__...__` stuff by your own params.

Comment: and then in the cellForRowAtIndexPath I would have to call this setFrame method?

Comment: one more question would be, is there a way to set the width of a custom cell to take all the space that is available in the UITableView?

Comment: Nope, your UITableView will automatically call it when it displays your cell.

Comment: (In reply to your second question:) you mean horizontally? Or all the vertical space available?